# Calling web service using Async task in android?

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

I have my separate web service class in which i just pass response method, url and array list of data which is required for making the request and getting the response. I call this web service in my login activity like this

```
JifWebService webServices = new JifWebService();
                webServices.Execute(RequestMethod.POST,
                        Jifconstant.LOGIN_URL, null, logindata);
                loginResponse = webServices.getResponse();
                loginResponseCode = webServices.getResponseCode();
```

In this login data is a array list which contains some data. Now i want to call this web service in background using async task. But i am just not getting it correctly. My web service logic is written in totally different java file and its working fine but i want to call my web service methods inside async task.`enter code here`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try below code for Async Task and also call web service in **doInBackground**:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AsyncExample extends Activity{


private String url="http://www.google.co.in";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     new AsyncCaller().execute();
}


private class AsyncCaller extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(AsyncExample.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("Loading...");
        pdLoading.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        //this method will be running on a background thread so don't update UI from here
        //do your long-running http tasks here, you don't want to pass argument and u can access the parent class' variable url over here


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        //this method will be running on UI thread

        pdLoading.dismiss();
    }

    }
}
```

**Done**