# how to call web service from custom list view adapter in android

Tags: android, listview

in Android I have a list view having two button accept and decline.
on click of accept button a web service to be called to accept and same for other button.
can I define  a class to call web service in my activity class and call it from my  custom adapter class
or can i define class  a class to call web service in my custom adapter class and call it from my  custom adapter class
Can any one help me out...plz help me.  i am stuck here

Comment: If I have understood your question I think you need an AsyncTask to call your webService from inside your adapter.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling web service using Async task in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23216038/calling-web-service-using-async-task-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
Use AsyncTask call method.

Click the accept button to call callwebservicefunction.

public class callwebservicefunction extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        public callsyncOperation(Handler getActivityTaskHandler) {
            ...........
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            //Here Call Your web service 
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //Here Call Your custom adapter class
        }

    }
```